# Can't ping after ip change

Tags: networking, ping, iptables

I'm running 3 virtual machines with Fedora 19.
The machine B is set up with two networks adapters and provides que channel between machine A and machine C.

The machine A IP is set to `192.168.1.1` and machine C IP is set to `172.16.1.1`
On machine B I have one adapter with IP `192.168.1.254`  and another adapter with IP `172.16.1.254`.

After flushing `iptables` on the tree machines I can `ping` all networks without any problems.

The problem is when I change the machine A to `192.168.1.3` with the command `ifconfig p2p1 192.168.1.3`

As of this moment I'm no more able to ping machine A from machine C.

What am I doing wrong?

After I do `ifuo p2p1` on machine A, it returns to the previous IP, that is, `192.168.1.1` and now I can ping machine A from machine C

Comment: Did you make sure the routing table was the same? Was there a default route?

Comment: I did not change any of the routing tables. Should I change? To what?

Comment: You should make sure they are the same after the IP change as before. When you change the IP, the OS may flush the routing table, requiring you to manually add back any routes you need. Likely you lost the default route.

Comment: Yep. That was the problem. Please submit an answer so I can select it as the correct one

Comment: maybe flush the ip tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add back any routes you need after changing the IP address. You likely lost the default route.

Answer (score 1):

While it's true that you always need to update routing tables if you remove an ip address that is used for default routing (already posted as an answer), you should also stop mixing various levels of commands.

The best way to control Linux kernel network configuration is the `ip` command from the *iproute* or *iproute2* package. It's the low-level interface for kernel networking, mostly useful for testing and debugging. You are using `ifconfig` which is similar (although deprecated) as it also talks directly to the kernel but performs some magic on top of that but fails badly in some situations. So far so good.

But mixing the low-level tools with distributions `ifup` unless you put the commands to the respective scripts is not a good idea. The `ifup` command controls network configuration tools like `/etc/sysconfig/network`, `/etc/network/interfaces` or `NetworkManager` which turn user configuration from disk files (and possible memory state as well) to the kernel.

So, while it is a valid answer that the routes have to be re-added, it's not clear whether you want to play with low-level tools to learn about networking, or you want to use your distribution's network configuration solution.

In the latter case, ignore `ifconfig` as well as `ip` (except for checking the final result) and perform the following steps:

- Edit your network configuration file.
- Tell the respective tool to reload (and apply) the configuration.

In Fedora 19 the configuration file resides in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts` and can be used either with the traditional *network-scripts* (`/etc/init.d/network`) or with *NetworkManager* if that one is installed an running. You can restart the service by `service network restart` or `service NetworkManager restart`, respectively (or use `systemctl` counterparts).

Answer (score 0):

You restart the service?

> /etc/init.d/networking restart

Best

Comment: That returns to the default IP `192.168.1.1`